# Android Database Contact Provider

Tags: android

The question is simple I have to enter in the phone Database contacts this type of value: username Phone (homework, mobile database, work) Email (Work) PhotoUri for synchronise contacts between two devices, up to now no problem here.

But how can i put a specific id to contact? or how can i update these values?

I hope there is someone who has tried it and has the patience to show us how we can do this, I looked up on the internet is there is nothing like this.

DATABASE DEVICE1<----->WEBPANEL<----->DATABASE DEVICE2

Comment: You shouldn't be inserting your own id values into the contact provider.

Comment: yes.., But I need that, there are other methods for synchronise?

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand what you're needing to synchronize. Google contacts? Isn't there an API explicitly for that?

Comment: Reference.  https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/

Comment: I have two address books, and I have to put in sync

Comment: Sure. Doesn't the documentation cover how to update that data?  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html

Comment: Now I have a look thanks and  for the  id?

Comment: Not sure. Sorry. I assume you are trying to sync some SQL database with the phones, which is a very broad and complicated topic, and strictly matching ID values is not necessarily the recommended approach